# MySQL start error - Failed to create a socket for IPv4 '127.0.0.1': errno: 13

Tags: mysql

I'm pulling my hair out over this one. Out of the blue (seemingly, I hadn't logged into the server in a couple of weeks) mysql died and I haven't been able to restart it. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. When attempting to restart, the following shows up in the log:

```
170502 18:00:57 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
170502 18:00:57 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
170502 18:00:57 [ERROR] Failed to create a socket for IPv4 '127.0.0.1': errno: 13.
170502 18:00:57 [ERROR] Can't create IP socket: Permission denied
170502 18:00:57 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Permissions, you say?

```
root@mleserver:~# ls -ld /var/run/mysqld/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 40 May  2 16:46 /var/run/mysqld/
```

That's not it.

```
root@mleserver:~# ls -la /var/lib/mysql
total 2521564
drwx------ 10 mysql mysql       4096 May  2 18:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 55 root  root        4096 May  2 16:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql          0 Oct  9  2013 debian-5.1.flag
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql          0 May  2 17:50 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 2569011200 May  2 18:00 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    5242880 May  2 18:00 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    5242880 May  2 18:00 ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 mysql mysql       4096 Aug 15  2016 mleserver_production
drwx------  2 mysql mysql       4096 May  2 17:50 mysql
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql          6 Jan 20 06:47 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 mysql mysql       4096 May  2 17:50 performance_schema
```

Doesn't look bad either.

```
root@mleserver:/tmp# cat /etc/passwd
...
mysql:x:104:111:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

I decided to nuke it from orbit:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

STILL the error persisted. Does anyone have any ideas? At this point I don't mind rebuilding the server from scratch out of frustration, BUT I want to be able to get the data from the database... though I need to be able to connect to it first. Here is my my.cnf file:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Try running with the default my.cnf or at least commenting out all of the port and socket lines if you haven't done so yet.  Also check to see if theres a mysql process still running that needs to be killed off.

Comment: Check if something else is listening on that port : _sudo netstat -anp | grep 3306_

Comment: There's no instance of mysql running, and there's nothing listening on 3306. Default my.cnf produces the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else, it turns out AppArmor was denying execution. From syslog

```
May  2 23:35:51 devanalyzer kernel: [24540.913056] type=1400 audit(1493782551.291:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=25601 comm="mysqld" family="inet" sock_type="stream" protocol=6
```

I don't care enough to diagnose it since I'm going to tear down this server, but I was able to get around it by setting all profiles to complain mode rather than enforce mode:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*
```

After that, `sudo service mysql start` worked as intended.